# Help to write LWU-NN algorithm in Latex -whats wrongg with my code

Tags: algorithms

[image: LWU-NN Algorithm]

Please can someone guide me as to how to write the algorithm attached in Latex I have tried and its giving me a lot of errors

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{LWU-NN Algorithm}
\label{LWU-NN Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{R\textendash Routing Table}{}
\For {R = 1 to size (Lt)}    
\For {C = 1 to size (Lt)}    
\State    $ L_{1} $= $Tr^{-1} Lt{x,y}+O $ 
\State   $  K={Tr}^{-1}\theta (x)$  % 
\For {i = 1 to size Lt)}
\For {j = 1 to size Tr}
\State $Tr_{ij}=K_{ij} + \rho_{ij} = Tr^{-1}\theta{x} $ $+$ $\rho_{ij}  $   
\EndFor
\EndFor
\State $P_{i}(Tr)=1/{2\pi}^{n/2} 1/N_{i} \sum_{i=1}^{N_i}e^{-{ Tr_{i}-Tr_{j} }^{-1} {Tr_{i}-Tr_{j} }}/{2\sigma^2 }$

\State \if ${I_{RC} > P {Tr}}$  % 
\State $Rt_{RC}= Lb {P {Tr}}$;
\EndIf
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been several times easier if I'd known which packages to load.

There are several problems:

- You have one more `\For` than `\EndFor`s;
- You have an `\EndIf` with no `\If`;
- You have an `\if` which is a regular conditional and not part of the markup for an algorithm, but you never close this. And, anyway, you can't use `\if` followed by a bit of pseudocode.

Fixing these issues:

[image: pseudocode]

If that is not quite the intended output, you'll have to adjust it. I wasn't always sure what you intended to say. (Should the `\if` have been an `\If`? Or was the `\State` intended and you meant the `\EndIf` to be `\EndFor`?)

Note that indenting your code consistently can help greatly in avoiding and finding typos, bugs and other weirdness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{LWU-NN Algorithm}
  \label{LWU-NN Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{R\textendash Routing Table}{}
      \For {R = 1 to size (Lt)}
        \For {C = 1 to size (Lt)}
          \State $L_{1} $= $Tr^{-1} Lt{x,y}+O $
          \State $K={Tr}^{-1}\theta (x)$
          \For {i = 1 to size Lt)}
            \For {j = 1 to size Tr}
              \State $Tr_{ij}=K_{ij} + \rho_{ij} = Tr^{-1}\theta{x} $ $+$ $\rho_{ij}$
            \EndFor
          \EndFor
          \State $P_{i}(Tr)=1/{2\pi}^{n/2} 1/N_{i} \sum_{i=1}^{N_i}e^{-{ Tr_{i}-Tr_{j} }^{-1} {Tr_{i}-Tr_{j} }}/{2\sigma^2 }$
          \If{${I_{RC} > P {Tr}}$}
            \State  $Rt_{RC}= Lb {P {Tr}}$;
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```